# Simplifying an integral in Gravitational Statistical Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration

I want to know if there is any way to simplify the following integral into a product or a power of a certain simpler one. The integral is of the form:

$$ Z_0=\int_{V^N} e^{-\beta Gm^2 \displaystyle\sum_{i<j}^N \frac{1}{|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|} } \cdot d^3\vec{r_1} \cdot ... \cdot d^3\vec{r_N}$$

Which comes from $N$ particles with gravity among them in a volume $V$. I'd like to know if it's possible to obtain something like:

$$Z_0  \propto \int_{V^2} e^{-\beta Gm^2 \frac{1}{|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|} } \cdot d^3\vec{r_i} d^3\vec{r_j} \hspace{1cm} \text{ or } \hspace{1cm}  Z_0  \propto \left(\int_{V^2} e^{-\beta Gm^2 \frac{1}{|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|} } \cdot d^3\vec{r_i} d^3\vec{r_j}\right)^{C(N)} $$

Or something similar or at least more manageable.